# How to add project of different workspace into the current workspace in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two workspaces and I want to use java file as a parent class or you can say extends it from workspace2 to workspace 1 in eclipse, how can I do this?
As I can add project from same workspace but unable to figure out from different workspace.
I dont want to import the project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But if you build the project, you need the parent java class to be in your project, anyway ...

Comment: is it not possible to extends java class from different workspace?

Comment: Workspaces are not a java thing, they are an Eclipse thing. You can access anything that's in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can make New File -> advanced options and Link to Folder in the system where the class is

Comment: That's how I would do it too.

Comment: it always will or you can make library some jar that you include in classpath like other libs

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I dont want to create any file in my workspace1, what I want is just give the 'extends java2' at class file so that I can inherit all the objects from it

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your project from workspace 2 to workspace 1.
You can reference your project in another workspace in the build path configuration of your project, linking two eclipse project, even if they are in different workspaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I dont want to create any file in my workspace1, what I want is just give the 'extends java2' at class file so that I can inherit all the objects from it

Comment: It's a option to generate a 'API' jar of your project2 with your class java2, and import in your project1 via maven or direct reference ? It's the way that i usually do that on my projects.

Comment: But the catch here is... if we want some changes in workspace2 project then I have to make jar file again... isnt it?

Comment: Yes, i think so. In my projects the workspace is the same, so i can modify both projects without remake the entire jar.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**

You can add the second project's src folder to the current project and you can add them in your project.

```
Right click on project -> Build path - > source tab - > link source
```

[image]

**Way 2 :**

Make that external project as a jar and add as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I dont want to create any file in my workspace1, what I want is just give the 'extends java2' at class file so that I can inherit all the objects from it

Comment: @LavishKarankar No. Without having it in your project, you can't. Even all the built in classes added to you as a Jar if you see.

Comment: one more question I have here is.. if we make a jar of a project and add into workspace1 then everytime whenever I make changes in workspace 2 then I have to make jar everytime... isnt it?

Comment: @LavishKarankar Yes. You have to. That is why we have jar's with version numbers :)

Comment: do we have any alternative.. means if I introduce Maven or something which helps me to get rid of updating again and again?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to be available for changes this are your options:

You have to either import the project or create a new workspace that includes them all.

Note that you may extend the java class from the same project or from another project within the workspace, but not from another workspace.

If you are willing not to have the code in front of you available for changes, you may build the first workspace' project into a jar and then use that as part of your other workspace.